# How can I clear the trails left by moving an SVG line?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, sprite

In a web app, I want to join two HTML element with a smooth line, and allow the user to move either element. The line should continue to join the two elements. I have created a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7v801wfb/4/) which illustrates the concept.

Here's the basic code I use for drawing the line, using jQuery:

```
$(function ready() {
    var $body = $("body")
    var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

    var $path = $(document.createElementNS(ns, "path"))
    $path.attr({
        "d": "M 5 5 C 100 5, 100 195, 195 195"
      , "stroke-width": 10
      , "stroke-linecap": "round"
      , stroke: "black"
      , fill: "none"
    })

    var svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg')
    var $svg = $(svg)
        .attr("version", "1.1")
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .attr("baseProfile", "tiny")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .append($path)

    $body.append($svg)
})
```

I use an SVG line between the moveable elements, and it leaves a trail each time it is redrawn. (This makes for very pretty feather-shaped designs, but that is not my purpose). How can I get the HTML page to refresh in the areas where the line is no longer present?

I know that if I were to do this using a canvas, I could copy the clean rect where the line is going to be drawn, then draw the line. Redrawing the line would consist of three steps:

- replacing the clean image of the dirtied rect
- copying the clean image of the rect that is about to be drawn on
- drawing the line

I am guessing that, when working with SVG elements, the process is rather different. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SVG, a line is an object. Don't create a new line, move the existing one. Save `$path`, and do `$path.attr('d', ".....")` with the new coordinates.